# Using regex incremental numbers in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to hide elements by their ids:

```
document.getElementById('Table1').style.display = 'none';
```

But there are many divs goes like Table1, Table2, Table3...

So how to use regular expressions in a situation like this?

Comment: Regular expressions aren't useful here. Do you want to use them for any particular reason?

Comment: My reason is to hide all elements with the id `Table*`. I think it requires regex, doesnt it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set class to all these elements. It was invented for such cases.

*HTML:*

```
<div id="Table1" class="myTables"></div>
<div id="Table2" class="myTables"></div>
<div id="Table3" class="myTables"></div>
```

*JavaScript:*

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myTables");
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

---

**UPDATE:** If setting classes is not applicable in your case, you can always use the modern method `querySelectorAll` with *attribute starts with* selector:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll("div[id^='Table']");
for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    elements[i].style.display = "none";
}
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/L2de8/

Comment: For specific reasons, it's not applicable to assign classes in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Regural expression will not work in this example.

Either use a common class name on all the elements, or, if you cannot change HTML, you can use [Selectors API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/REC-selectors-api-20130221/) to select the elements you need to hide.

Use

```
var allElemsWithIdStartingFromTable =  document.querySelectorAll('[id^="Table"]');
```

to select all elements with ID starting with "Table", so it would be Table1, Table2, but also TableOfProducts, keep that in mind.

Then you need to iterate over this and check if the id attribute matches `/^Table\d+$/` regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

for example..if you give myTables as class name for div..use that for lenght..

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("myTables");//to know the length only..
        for(var i=0;i<elements.length;i++)
        {
        document.getElementById('Table'+i).style.display = 'none';
        }
```

use looping concept..its an example..

Comment: @VisioN your way is good..i like your answer..for length purpose there is no other way..i felt your is better way..